# Clicking on image using RSpec & Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm using Rspec and Capybara.

I am attempting to click an image, but cannot find a way to get Capybara to click the image. I'm not sure what to do, as I have in fact same class, alt and src.

Thanks

Example of html

```
<tr class="even">
  <td class="gridData" style="text-align:center;">
  <td class="gridData"> 221 </td>
  <td class="gridData" route="default" reset="0" urlparams="users index edit {userID}" label="Username">
  <td class="gridData">
  <img class="user-info-grid" alt="info" src="/themes/system/images/icon/16/information.png">
  </td>
</tr>

 <tr class="odd">
  <td class="gridData" style="text-align:center;">
  <td class="gridData"> 222 </td>
  <td class="gridData" route="default" reset="0" urlparams="users index edit {userID}" label="Username">
  <td class="gridData">
  <img class="user-info-grid" alt="info" src="/themes/system/images/icon/16/information.png">
```

In fact here is the source, which I want to test:

```
  <img class="user-info-grid" alt="info" src="/themes/system/images/icon/16/information.png">
```

But as I said, I cannot find a way to get Capybara to click the image.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, your HTML is not well-formed. There is no such thing as an image in a table row. That code will make all browsers render in quirks mode. You should make yourself familiar with the basics of HTML.

Comment: It's an image that open a js pop-up

Comment: Cool, but that doesn't change the fact that the standard doesn't allow to have an `img` in a `tr` (table row) :-)

Answer (score 12):

You can use this:

```
page.first(".user-info-grid").click
```

This is use to find **user-info-grid** class and apply click function.

If multiple classes are comes with this name then the click will execute in first found class.

Answer (score 9):

You can use that when looking for an id:

```
find("#the_id").click
```

Or for a class

```
find(".the_class").click
```

Comment: This worked for me. Clean and simple. Thanks!
**Correction** While OP was looking for a `class` solution, I found this in search of an `id` solution. Looks like suresh.g's answer is more on par with OP. Upvoting both.

Comment: You should be able to search for a class as well by replacing the "#" by a ".". ex : find(".the_class").click

Answer (score 1):

I put this and works:

```
  find("img[src*='myphoto.jpg']").click
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your image is an image, not a link. Wrap it inside a link first, then click the link, like so:

```
<a href="..." id="my_link"><img ... /></a>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. There is no link, you are right... It's js based pop-up, which I want to open by clicking on it

Comment: I know little about Capybara, but I would assume that if you ask it to find a link on your page, it looks for an HTML anchor. Moreover, the default driver in Capybara is completely oblivious to any form of JavaScript on your page. Have a look at e.g. the Selenium driver, which is able to process dynamic page elements.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that there's no `<a>` element because you're using a JavaScript `onclick` handler? If so, then you need to be aware that plain Capybara doesn't do JavaScript. You need to use [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit), Selenium, or something else similar.

But I'd advise you to put in the `<a>` element, and apply the JS handler to that. That will make it easier for user agents without JavaScript to handle (yes, there still are some!).

And Matthias is right: make your HTML valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try using XPath, if not that then you can use either visit_to the source of the link, or you can use try help on http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a link, it's an onclick JS handler